# Update document with its value

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Need to update a document based its value

```
var filter = Builders<UnitTravelHistory>.Filter.Empty;
var update = Builders<UnitTravelHistory>.Update.Set(i => i.JobDuration, i.A-i.B)
DBContext.ClientDb.Repository<UnitTravelHistory>(collection).UpdateMany(filter, update);
```

here A and B are 2 fields in the collection. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use pipeline updates in order to refer to fields of the document being updated like so:

```cs
var pipelineStage = BsonDocument.Parse("{$set:{JobDuration:{$subtract:['$A','$B']}}}");

collection.UpdateMany(
    _ => true, 
    Builders<UnitTravelHistory>.Update.Pipeline(new[] { pipelineStage })
);
```

here's an [alternative](https://gist.github.com/dj-nitehawk/b71e0a143422188f7ec39fa4ad9c68cb)

Comment: Update.Pipeline not available

Comment: am using MongoDB.Driver, Version=2.4.3.23,

Comment: looks like you need at least [driver v2.9](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_UpdateDefinitionBuilder_1_Pipeline.htm) and server v4.2

Comment: is there any solution with .Driver, Version=2.4.3.23 and  mongodb 4

Comment: @user2972244 not that I'm aware of.